# Replacement for Jenkins Scriptler plugin?

Tags: security, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-scriptler

It looks like the Jenkins Scriptler plugin is no longer available, due to security reasons: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin

"Distribution of This Plugin Has Been Suspended"

Is there a similar plugin that I could use to run saved Groovy scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi you can store your groovy scripts in Managed Files and pass the parameters to groovy script through Extended Choice Parameters Plugin.

Or else you can download Scriptler plugin source code and add it to your /var/lib/jenkins/plugin folder and start Jenkins server. It will work fine.

Comment: I just released an alpha version (3.0-alpha) of scriptler with all security issues fixed to the experimental update center

Comment: @domi will this 3.0 scriptler permit the "Prepare an environment for the run" run a groovy scriptler script, but on the master within the system workspace? I query various upstream builds to get and import their environment.

Comment: I know this post is old but can someone maybe have a look at [#54107733](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54107733/read-config-file-in-jenkins-groovy-script-for-build-parameters#comment103985485_54107733) here on Stackoverflow? The question is, how to use Active Choice Parameters or Extended Choice Parameters with a groovy script stores with Managed Files.

Answer (score 0):

For removed plugins: You can find the .hpi file on archive sites on the internet, and then in Jenkins in Manage Plugins, use the "Advanced" tab > "Upload Plugin" to install it.