# Jenkins manages groovy scripts without scriptler plugin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

Since [scriptler plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Scriptler+Plugin) has some security issues and it's not safe for use, what is the alternative plugins to manage the groovy scripts ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you configure your job as a pipeline?  If so, Groovy can be run inside the pipeline steps.

Also, maybe check the suggestions here:
[Replacement for Jenkins Scriptler plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44577281/replacement-for-jenkins-scriptler-plugin)