# Read Config file in jenkins groovy script for build parameters

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I have a choice list for a parameter. The values in choice list is based on user who logs in jenkins. 
For example a student opts for subjects maths science and commerce, he should be able to see his own subjects in the choice drop down.

I have the mapping of each student with their enrolled subject in a json file. I used [Config File Provider plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin) to refer this file in jenkins. Now how should I load this configuration files through groovy script in the choice parameters. I am using [Extended Choice Paremater](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) and [Active Choice Parameter plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin)

Comment: Found a solution? We were doing it with scriptler and [Active Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) but since scriptler is deprecated due to security issues, I wanted to store scripts with [Config File Provider Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin) and call them with some plugin, for example Active Choice Parameter or Extended Choice Parameter. Both offer the possibility to execute a groovy script but I have to paste the script to a textfield instead of using the one stored with Config File Provider.

Answer (score 2):

I use the below groovy script to access added config files from groovy script. See if it helps

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles
import org.jenkinsci.lib.configprovider.model.Config;
Config config = GlobalConfigFiles.get().getById("Your config file ID here")
println(config.content)`
```