# Jenkins Dynamic Parameter Plug-in

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-scriptler

Anyone know of a replacement for the Dynamic Parameter Plug-in?  I want to execute existing scriptlers.  Appears that Dynamic Parameter Plug-in was removed from Jenkins plug-in site.  Suggestions for other plugin that would work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Parameter Plug-in appears to have been pulled for [security issues](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in). It  was [pulled at the same time](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-04-10/#dynamic-parameter-plugin) as the [Scriptler](https://plugins.jenkins.io/scriptler/) plugin, also for [security issues](https://www.jenkins.io/security/advisory/2017-04-10/#scriptler-plugin), but is back.

The plugin may no longer be in the Update Center, but you can grab it from [GitHub](https://github.com/jenkinsci/dynamicparameter-plugin/releases).  Keep in mind it's 8.5+ years since the last release and is likely no longer supported. Your risk.

The [Dynamic Extended Choice Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/dynamic_extended_choice_parameter/) also has issues but remains.

Have you looked at [Active Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/),  [Extensible Choices](https://plugins.jenkins.io/extensible-choice-parameter/) or any of the other [Build Parameter](https://plugins.jenkins.io/ui/search/?labels=parameter) tagged plugins?

There are alternatives if you just need the [Scriptler scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45034829/598141).